# Bouncycastle jar versions (few old versions are not compatible with new versions and among themselves too)

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

What version combination of BouncyCastle jars in java (bcprov, bcmail, bctsp, and others if any) are best compatible with each other to work with digital signature, certificate generation, timestamping, ocsp etc ?

(few old versions are not compatible with new versions and among themselves too)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the most recent versions?

Comment: If your application was build with the previous versions and now if you need to update your libraries then your project could show errors and hence you also might need to change your implementations (a little bit)

Comment: True, but if you have an existing application then you're already updating one of the bouncycastle jars and exposing yourself to these problems, so updating them all would seem reasonable in that case. The problem is that the bouncycastle development team appears to be quite small, like maybe 3-ish people. I don't think they have a complete compatibility matrix between versions and creating one would be a huge undertaking. The best you can hope for is using a set of releases that were all current at the same time.